# How can I retrieve Twilio incoming calls between two dates using PHP?

Tags: twilio-api, twilio-php

I've checked a number of related articles, and the script returns all of the calls, no matter what dates I use.

I am using the following, but get the same results every time I change the dates, it seems to be listing all the calls made to all the phone numbers I use in the following code:

```
$calls = $twilio->calls->read([
    "status" => "completed", 
    "to" => "$myNumber",
    'StartTime>' => '2023-07-04',
    'StartTime<' => '2023-07-06'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter [is `startTime`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#read-multiple-call-resources), not `StartTime`, and you should be using `endTime` for the end, not `startTime` again.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I am still getting the same results when I change it to the following:  $calls = $client->calls->read([
        "status" => "completed", 
        "to" => "$myNumber",
        'startTime<=' => '2023-08-17',
        'endTime>=' => '2023-07-17'
    ]);
    echo count($calls) . "\t" . $record->phoneNumber . "\t" . $record->friendlyName . "\n";

Comment: `'startTime<=' => ` is incorrect syntax now, and your end time is now before your start time, which is impossible without a time machine.

Comment: Great, I'm making progress I think.  I can now find and list calls that start and end on a certain date, but when I try to find the calls in between two dates, what I get is all of the calls.  What is the correct syntax for this?

Comment: `'startTime' => '>=2023-07-04'` and `'endTime' => '<=2023-07-06'` in your argument array. Do be sure to read the linked documentation, especially the bits around "after midnight of this date" so you make sure you're getting the right values. You might also consider sending a date *and* time, i.e. `2023-07-17 00:00:00` to be super clear.

Comment: Thanks for working me through this.  When I use:  $calls = $twilio->calls->read([
    "status" => "completed", 
    "to" => "$myNumber",
    'startTime' => '>=2023-07-04',
    'endTime' => '<=2023-07-06'
]);  I wind up getting a PHP fatal error saying Invalid date value.

Comment: It's a little unclear from the documentation, but you may have to try something like `'startTime' => 'StartTime>=2023-07-04'`. Get the simpler approach of just plain old `'startTime' => '2023-07-04'` style querying working, first, though.